# Draw epipolar lines over images with distortion

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I have a stereo rig calibrated using OpenCV with the chessboard algorithm.
My reprojection error is about 0.16 (I suppose this is actually ok).

I got my distortion coefficients for both cameras and the fundamental matrix F.

Suppose I want to draw some epipolar lines on an image pair.
I did the following procedure:

1. Undistort images (keeping the **same** camera matrix)
2. Find corresponding epipolar lines using F
3. Draw lines

Is it correct? Results seems *quite* perfect.

But I suppose that, due to distortion, no perfectly straight epipolar lines can be drawn.
Is this correct?